# What is the fastest way to section data

Tags: c#

I am not sure what this is called so Ill explain by giving an example. I have an array of numbers

```
76425
234786234
56
4356
564356
456
94
900
725
```

Now I would like to join this data and make a new array that looks like this

```
76425,234786234,56,4356
564356,456,94,900
725
```

This is a string array that contains 3 items. Items per row is 4. As you can see the last row only has one item. That is ok. Here is the code I have written to do this:

```
 numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns > lineCount ? lineCount : numberOfColumns;
 int newLineCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Convert.ToDouble(lineCount))/numberOfColumns));
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < newLineCount; i++)
 {
      var page = lines.Skip(numberOfColumns * i).Take(numberOfColumns).Select(xx => xx.Trim());
      sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",",page));
 }
```

This code works just fine. But it is very slow. Do you have any ideas to make it faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append(lines[i]);
    if ((i % 4) == 3)
        sb.AppendLine();
    else
        sb.Append(',');
}
```

Comment: Wow..I tried this one and it is blistering fast. I doubt it will go faster than this. Thank you

Comment: Actually string manipulation is slower than numbers (ints, longs, etc.).  What is the source of your data? That is what is going to depend on how this should be done.  Is it from a text file or from a database?

Comment: @tsells - It is coming from a textbox in the local windows form. The data can either be text or numbers. Do you know a faster way to process this?

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the number of iterations will increase performance.

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i+=4)
{
 result.Add(string.Format ("{0},{1},{2},{3}", lines[i], lines[i+1], lines[i+2], lines[i+3]));
}
```

Also, you could use parallel processing, if you have a multicore processor.

```
 var linesPerProcessor = (int)(((lines.Count/4) / Environment.ProcessorCount)*4);
 Parallel.For(0,Environment.ProcessorCount -1
            ) =>
                {
                   for (int i = (p * linesPerProcessor); i < (p+1)*linesPerProcessor; i+=4)
                   {
                          result.Add(string.Format ("{0},{1},{2},{3}", 
                                lines[i], lines[i+1], lines[i+2], lines[i+3]));
                   }
                }
            );
```

Comment: the only problem with this is the "items per row" always changes. In my example it was four but it can go up 20.

Comment: Well, you asked for the "fastest". To change the items per row, all you have to do is replace 4 by the number of items you want, And generate the "format string" accordingly. It'll still be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var arr = new[]
    {
        76425,
234786234,
56,
4356,
564356,
456,
94,
900,
725,
    };

var result =
    arr.Select((x, i) => new {x, i})
    .GroupBy(t => t.i / 4)
    .Select(t => string.Join(",", t.Select(v => v.x)));
```

Output:

```
76425,234786234,56,4356
564356,456,94,900
725
```